# How Can Access to My Windows 10 Desktop Directory From Ubuntu Terminal

Tags: filesystem, windows-10

I install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 . Now , I want to access some folder which is in my Windows 10 Desktop directory.

I try some command like this on Ubuntu terminal but I can't find Desktop directory.
`cd /media/usr/16a1c8ab-4046-4f46-9c72-3cefa5c7ad79`  etc.

Answer (score 2):

Your Windows `c:\` file-system should be mounted on 'mnt'.
To get to your desktop directory try 
`cd /mnt/c/Users/*windows-username*/Desktop/`

Comment: Windows is not automatically mounted on /mnt by default.

Comment: It is nowadays!

Answer (score 2):

The Windows 10 partition is not mounted by default. First, find out where your Windows partition is:

```
lsblk -f
```

You will find one or more partitions with an FSTYPE of `ntfs`. There may be one with a label of "Recovery"; that is not the one you are looking for. The Windows 10 partition may be named `sda4` for example. Now do:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/mywindowsdrive                 # you need to do this only once
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sda4 /mnt/mywindowsdrive
```

Be careful to replace `sda4` by whatever your Windows 10 drive is named.
Now your Windows files and folders can be found in `/mnt/mywindowsdrive`. If this is not the right partition, do

```
sudo umount /mnt/mywindowsdrive
```

and try another partition.

If you don't want to issue a `mount` command after every reboot, consider adding a line to `/etc/fstab`. How you do this can be found elsewhere on this site.

Comment: thanks a lot for this info. It already helped me trying to solve part pf my problem: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/579116/how-to-find-windows-drive-cd-host-is-not-working. I would be very grateful if you could take a quick look, since i cant find the correct partition. If you dont have the time, thanks anyways for this answer!!